# SQLiteAssetHelper insert/delete/update

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm considering using [SQLiteAssetHelper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) library in my app. I actually found out how to read the datas from the DB, but i have no clue about how to insert/delete/update them.
Is this even possible ?
Thank you for helping me !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public Database open() throws SQLException{
        ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
        ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;        
    }

   public void close() {
        ourHelper.close();
   }



    public long createEntry(String product, String kcal, String eenheid) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(FEILD1, field1);
        cv.put(FEILD2, field2);
        cv.put(FEILD13, field3);
        return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The same way you'd do with a regular `SQLiteOpenHelper`. Obtain a `SQLiteDatabase` object with `getWritableDatabase()` and do your CRUD operations on it.